# How to parse a json having Rows and Columns

Tags: apex, visualforce, callout, scheduled-apex, apexrest

I have the below JSON and want to parse it out to get the data. But the JSON format is in Rows and Columns.

```
{
   "returnValue":{
      "columnNames":[
         "RowID",
         "personID",
         "Name"
      ],
      "columnLabels":[
         "RowID",
         "PersonID",
         "Name"
      ],
      "columnDataTypes":[
         "Integer",
         "String",
         "String"
      ],
      "rows":[
         {
            "data":[
               "1",
               "1",
               "PRD_Test"
            ]
         },
         {
            "data":[
               "2",
               "10001",
               "Test-RIH_pRD"
            ]
         },
         {
            "data":[
               "2",
               "10001",
               "Test-RIH_pRD"
            ]
         },
         {
            "data":[
               "2",
               "10001",
               "Test-RIH_pRD"
            ]
         },
         {
            "data":[
               "3",
               "10001",
               "Test-RIH_pRD"
            ]
         },
         {
            "data":[
               "4",
               "10001",
               "Test-RIH_pRD"
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Below is the JSON parser class for the above JSON.

```
public class JSON2Apex {

public ReturnValue returnValue;

public class ReturnValue {
    public List<String> columnNames;
    public List<String> columnLabels;
    public List<String> columnDataTypes;
    public List<Rows> rows;
}

public class Rows {
    public List<String> data;
}


public static JSON2Apex parse(String json) {
    return (JSON2Apex) System.JSON.deserialize(json, JSON2Apex.class);
} }
```

How I can get the data from this format as a key value?

Answer (score 1):

You can parse like this :

> ReturnValue response = ReturnValue.parse(Value In String);

And iterate using like this :

```
for(String rc : response.columnNames){
    System.debug(rc);
}
```